# Unit Testing location in async-await in angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, async-await

I am using Angular 9+ with karma test runner and jasmine test framework for unit tests.

I wanted to unit test only *`app component`* which has a dependency injection:

`app.component.ts`

```
import { Component, EmbeddedViewRef } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment-timezone';
import { OtherServiceService } from './other-service.service';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private sampleService: OtherService, private location: Location){}

    async func(){
        await this.sampleService.func2().toPromise();
        console.log('Async call completed');
        this.location.go('/index.html');
    }
}
```

`other-service.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class OtherServiceService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  func2(){
    return this.http.post('' , null);
  }
}
```

The unit test i have tried so far:

```
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { TestBed, async, fakeAsync, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { OtherServiceService } from './other-service.service';

const locationStub = {
  go: jasmine.createSpy('go')
}

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let otherServiceStub;
  let fixture, component;
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    otherServiceStub = jasmine.createSpyObj(['func2']);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        {provide: OtherServiceService , useValue: otherServiceStub},
        {provide: Location, useValue: locationStub}
    ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it('should create the app', () => {
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should check for correct logs',fakeAsync(() => {
    otherServiceStub.func2.and.returnValue(of('Garbage'));
    const location = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(Location);
    let spyObj = spyOn(console,'log');
    component.func();
    tick();
    expect(spyObj).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Async call completed');
    expect(location.go).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/index.html');
 }));


});
```

On running ng test --code-coverage, it always shows error **`Expected spy go to have been called with: [ '/index.html' ] but it was never called.`**.

On the coverage report, it shows the line as covered (this.location.go) , but the test fails, and I can't seem to understand why. I have also taken help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48202042/angular-how-to-test-a-component-which-requires-a-location), but to no success.

**`UPDATE 1.0`**:

I have tried as suggested by @AliF50:

```
  async func(){
    await this.sampleService.func2().toPromise();
    console.log('Async call completed');
    this.location.go('/index.html');
    console.log('After location go in component');
  }
```

```
  it('should check for correct logs',fakeAsync(() => {
    otherServiceStub.func2.and.returnValue(of('Garbage'));
    let spyObj = spyOn(console,'log');
    component.func();
    tick();
    const location = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(Location);
    expect(spyObj).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Async call completed');
    console.log('Before location go in test');
    expect(location.go).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/index.html');
    console.log('After location go in test');
 }));
```

**But to my suprise *none* of the `console logs` are being printed, even though it shows lines as covered.**

**`UPDATE 2.0`**:

As suggested by @AliF50:

```
  it('should check for correct logs',fakeAsync(() => {
    otherServiceStub.func2.and.returnValue(of('Garbage'));
    let spyObj = spyOn(console,'log').and.callThrough();
    component.func();
    tick();
    const location = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(Location);
    expect(spyObj).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Async call completed');
    console.log('Before location go in test');
    expect(location.go).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/index.html');
    console.log('After location go in test');
 }));
```

**All the `console logs` are being printed, but the error still remains.**

**`UPDATE 3.0`**:
**Any luck anyone? It is still an open question**

**`UPDATE 4.0`**:
**Thanks to Andrei. Question is solved now.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after so much time, and `@Andrei`'s contribution, I was able to come up with the answer to this question:

```
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { TestBed, async, fakeAsync, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { OtherServiceService } from './other-service.service';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

fdescribe('AppComponent', () => {
  let otherServiceStub;
  let fixture, component;
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    otherServiceStub = jasmine.createSpyObj(['func2']);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        {provide: OtherServiceService , useValue: otherServiceStub},
        Location
    ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it('should create the app', () => {
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should check for correct logs',async () => {
    otherServiceStub.func2.and.returnValue(of('Garbage'));
    let locationObj = TestBed.inject(Location);
    let spyObj = spyOn(locationObj,'go');
    await component.func();
    expect(spyObj).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/index.html');
 });


});
```

The Unit test is passing now with all the lines are being shown as covered.

Answer (score 1):

there is a problem with promises and async await in js, they can't be synchronised by any means. So if your code involves using async/await the correct way would be to make your test function also async.

```
it('should check for correct logs',async () => {
   otherServiceStub.func2.and.returnValue(of('Garbage'));
   let spyObj = spyOn(console,'log').and.callThrough();
   await component.func();
   expect(spyObj).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Async call completed');
});
```

whole test with location check should look like

```
const locationStub = {
  go: jasmine.createSpy('go')
}
...
it('should check for correct navigation', async () => {
  otherServiceStub.func2.and.returnValue(of('Garbage'));
  await component.func();
  const location = TestBed.get(Location); // or just locationStub can be referred directly here
  expect(location.go).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/index.html');
});
```

Comment: thanks a ton. Just one more thing in this question. Is it possible to do a spyOn on go() function in location and check whther it is called with /index.html or not? Can you help me by writing a test spec for the same? something like expect(location.go).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/index.html')?

Comment: you have the correct piece of code to test that. there is just a shorter way to inject it in test
`const location = TestBed.inject(Location);` or `.get(Location)` if you are using old angular version

Comment: Can you write the piece of code of the test spec (with the expect statement)? I am not getting it completely. Thank you

Comment: Please help me with this (the location.go part) . I was stuck in this question for a long time and only now because of you i am on the verge of solving it completely.

Comment: i provided an example in answer

Comment: same error Andrei. ```Expected spy go to have been called with:
  [ '/index.html' ]
but it was never called.``` .

Comment: hm, everything looks normal. is the AppComponent code up to date with the code we are testing?

Comment: I have not touched the AppComponent code from the time of posting the question :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228754/discussion-between-kl-kisne-dekha-hai-and-andrei).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
describe('App component' , () => {
let otherServiceStub;
let component: AppComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

beforeEach(async(() => {

otherServiceStub = jasmine.createSpyObj(['func2']);

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
   declarations: [AppComponent],
   providers: [{
     provide: OtherService , useValue: otherServiceStub
   }]
}).compileComponents();

}));

beforeEach(() => {
   fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
   component = fixture.componentInstance;
});

it('should check for correct logs',fakeAsync(() => {
   otherServiceStub.func2.and.returnValue(of('Garbage'));
   let spyObj = spyOn(console,'log');
   component.func();
   tick(); // remove the 1000 to remove time elapsing of 1000ms but instead
           // to wait until all promises resolve
   expect(spyObj).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Async call completed');
}));


});
```

Comment: Sorry Ali for the confusion, I forgot to add something earlier and the issue was resolved both by your approach and mine, now I have changed the question a bit. Please help me with the same. Thank you in advance for your efforts.

Comment: I looked at your new code, it seems to be good. Try adding logs in the test before and after `expect(location.go)` and after `this.location` in the component. Make sure the order of the logs are `Async call completed` then `Location.go called` then (now in the test) `expecting location.go was called` then `after expecting location.go was called`.

Comment: I have tried as you told, but nothing seems to log. Can you see it from your end? Also can you upvote this question so that more people can also help.

Comment: I upvoted. Change the `let spyObj = spyOn(console,'log');` to `let spyObj = spyOn(console,'log').and.callThrough();` so we actually do the console logging and it is not stubbed.

Comment: Hello Ali, i did as you told and the result was all 4 console logs getting printed but the error that it was never called still remains. Logs :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::Async call completed
 After location go in component
 Before location go in test
 After location go in test

Comment: That's strange, I am not sure then.