# Unit Testing Http Calls in Angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, httprequest

I am using Angular 9+.

While `unit testing` services that implement **`httpClient`** and make http requests, I referred this [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests) by Angular Team. I followed the process and got success in the unit tests also.
Following is the code (taken from the doc):

```
it('can test HttpClient.get', () => {
  const testData: Data = {name: 'Test Data'};

  // Make an HTTP GET request
  httpClient.get<Data>(testUrl)
    .subscribe(data =>
      // When observable resolves, result should match test data
      expect(data).toEqual(testData)
    );

  // The following `expectOne()` will match the request's URL.
  // If no requests or multiple requests matched that URL
  // `expectOne()` would throw.
  const req = httpTestingController.expectOne('/data');

  // Assert that the request is a GET.
  expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');

  // Respond with mock data, causing Observable to resolve.
  // Subscribe callback asserts that correct data was returned.
  req.flush(testData);

  // Finally, assert that there are no outstanding requests.
  httpTestingController.verify();
});
```

My question is:

- Since `http calls` are `asynchronous`, why is not fakeAsync() written in any of the tests provided in the docs? Like normally when unit testing **`asynchronous methods`** ( `setTimeout() , setInterval()` ), the docs provided in angular shows that we need a fake zone.js which appends all the async requests to an array and then we use flushMicrotasks() or tick() to further facilitate the calls.
- How is the control flow happening when `req.flush()` is called? We have made a call to the function `httpClient.get<Data>(testUrl)` which subscribes to the observable and and **flush** is used to just resolve it. So the entire flow in the test spec is happening async / sync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the nature of rxjs allows you to handle streams without thinking wether they are synchronious or asynchronious. for testing http client things are made synchroniuous for ease of testing. httpClient is made in a way that async code is behaving sync in tests, because every "async" work is based on rxjs streams. streams api is strong enough to make async logic - sync in some cases. by async in js world it is usually ment that before execution of this code, js execution callstack should become empty

`req.flush(...);` will invoke subscribe handler inside of your component just in this line. just after it you can assert the result of that handler

Comment: thanks for the answer. However can you be a bit more elaborative? I am a beginner in Angular so I can't fully understand you. Like is httpClient made in a way that async code is behaving sync in tests? Also until i do a req.flush(), the observable does not get resolved which seems async to me. However the test is synchronous.

Comment: httpClient is indeed made in a way that async code is behaving sync in tests, because every "async" work is based on rxjs streams. streams api is strong enough to make async logic - sync in some cases. by async in js world it is usually ment that  before execution of this code, js execution callstack should become empty

Comment: ok thanks. Can you update your answer with this information also? After that I will mark it as an answer. Also can you upvote this question so that it reaches more number of people who might be in same dilemma?

Comment: I want one more favour from your side ( if possible ). This question of mine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65295364/unit-testing-location-in-async-await-in-angular is still to be complete with an answer, can you help me out?