# How can I test external link navigation in Karma?

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I'm using Angular as my framework,
and I have some external links within my app.

In order to stop user from leaving when there's unsaved changes,
I made a little hack that forces the application to run through angulars,
life cycle, and if Angular gives the OK, only then navigation should happen.

and it looks like this:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="menu-list list-unstyled">
  <li class="item" *ngFor="let menu of menuList">
    <a (click)="navigate($event, menu.url)" href="{{ menu.url }}">
      {{ menu.name}}
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**TypeScript**

```
navigate(event: MouseEvent, URL: string): void {
  event.preventDefault(); // Not to navigate through anchor
  this.router.navigate(['/']).then((success) => {
  if (success) {
    window.location.href = URL; // I want to test that this happens
  }
  });
}
```

So far so good,
But this logic is kind of hacky,
so I want to write a test to make sure it's not meddled with.
That's where things get hairy:

```
it('Should navigate after successful canDeactivate', fakeAsync(() => {
  const uniqueTestURL = 'testURL';
  component.menuList = [
  {
    id: 'test',
    name: 'testRoute',
    url: uniqueTestURL,
  }];
  fixture.detectChanges();
  const navigationItem = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css(`.menu-list .item a`));
  navigationItem.nativeElement.click();
  tick();
  const currentURL = window.location.href;
  expect(currentURL).toEqual(uniqueTestURL);
}));
```

In how it's written here,
Karma will throw 404 warn, which won't pass the test:

```
WARN [web-server]: 404: /testURL
Disconnected (0 times), because no message in 60000 ms.
```

I also tried setting proxies within karma.js (proxies: {'/testURL': ''}), I wouldn't get 404, but the test would fail on the account of:

```
Expected 'http://localhost:1234/context.html' to equal 'testURL'
```

I also tried adding optional parameters to the current URL used in the test (window.location.href + '?testcase')
but I get the following error(even if I set the tick for 5000ms):

```
Expected 'http://localhost:1234/context.html' to equal 'http://localhost:1234/context.html?testCase'.
```

as well as tried to navigate to this url: 'http://localhost:1234/debug.html' which I know karma has,
but it caused the next error:

```
 Error: Expected 'http://localhost:1234/context.html' to equal 'http://localhost:1234/debug.html'.
```

So my question is, can I navigate somehow to a somewhat different URL then my ChromeHeadles is currently on(during the test), with the tests keep running?

is there another way to test if window.location.href was changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling `window.location` use the `Location` service provided by Angular - it's basically a wrapper for `window.location`. Inject it as a dependency in the constructor `private location: Location`. In your unit tests you then provide a mock value for that service, and spy on the relevant methods

Good example of testing with `Location`:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/48202957/271012

Depending on what `location` methods you need, you might also choose to inject `DOCUMENT`, and access it's `location` property

```js
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
...
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) { }

goToUrl(): void {
    this.document.location.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com';
}
```

The mocks would be similar

Comment: No way to navigate to an external link using angular's Location.

Comment: Using Angular's document wrapper,
I was able to test it, because it allowed me to provide value, and then spy on it.
Thank you